# How does a multi-column index work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

More specifically, what data structure does MYSQL use for multi-column indexing?
I know MYSQL use Btree for indexing, which can only index one column. How does multi-column indexing work then?

Comment: *I know MYSQL use Btree for indexing, which can only index one column.* Your knowledge is incorrect. BTree can index only one **expression**. And this single expression may include complex combination of columns, literals, operators, deterministic functions... the only requirement is that this complex expression must give scalar value.

Comment: @Akina - Well, that is 'wrong', too.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a MySQL "composite" index this way.

Concatenate all the columns in the index together, then build an BTree index on that 'single' string.

Some related comments:

Once you understand that analogy, you can see why the cardinality of the individual columns does not matter.  That is, the order of the columns in a composite index does not matter *for performance*.  The order *does* matter, depending on what the query asks for.

`INDEX(a,b)` is likely to be useful for these:

```
 WHERE a = 123
 WHERE b = 5 AND a = 678
```

But cannot be used for

```
 WHERE b = 5
```

(Note on my use of "concatenate".  Since it is not really practical to concatenate floats, dates, signed integers, strings with odd collations, etc as if they were just bytes, I do not mean that InnoDB literally concatenates the bytes together.)